# comparing pointer value that's an asterisk in C

Tags: c

I'm a beginner currently trying to detect if an argument has been passed is equal to one of the characters in an array. The format of the arguement is `integer -> operator -> integer`.

For some reason whenever the `*` character is given, my program is unable to detect it; Or it dosen't respond to it. Now I know that `*` is used to dereference a pointer, but how can I get that pointer to get me the value of `*`

```
char operators[] = {'*','+','/','-','%'};
int possibleAmountOfOperators = sizeof(operators) / sizeof(char);
int i = 0;

for( i = 0; i < possibleAmountOfOperators; i++){
  if(*type_of_arg[2] == operators[i]){
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `type_of_arg`?

Comment: type_of_arg is whatever argument is passed through the command line

Answer (score 3):

I guess your problem is not your program but the invocation of it. Try quoting * when you pass it as a parameter so that it's not expanded by the shell.

Comment: Thank you!.. that works but is there a way around that so I dont have to quote it in the invocation?

Comment: No. That's from the shell.